# How to show Storyboard UI using NSExtensionPrincipalClass for sharing extension

Tags: ios, swift, ios8-share-extension, share-extension

I am implementing share extension functionality in iOS app. I am able to use "NSExtensionPrincipalClass" in share extension's Info.plist file. And I have added custom MyViewController i.e.

```
import UIKit
@objc(MyViewController)

class MyViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print("My view loaded!!!!")
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
}
```

I have created storyboard with "MyViewController" and it's sample UI.

How do I show UI from storyboard created for "MyViewController".?

When I run the app it prints "My view loaded!!!!" but not able to bind to UI i.e. UI is blank. How do I set UI for MyViewController from storyboard?

Answer (score 3):

You need to replace `NSExtensionPrincipalClass` with [`NSExtensionMainStoryboard`](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/AppExtensionKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014212-SW14):

> **NSExtensionMainStoryboard**
>
> `String` - iOS, macOS. Specifies the name of the app extension’s main storyboard file, minus the `.storyboard` filename extension. This key, if used, must be placed as an immediate child of the [NSExtension](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/AppExtensionKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014212-SW9) key.